# Colorize shape "part by part"

Tags: objective-c, shapes, fill, colorize

I'd like to colorize a shape, for example a rectangle, part by part. For example, if I click on a button, I'd like to colorize a part of the rectangle and add the "amount" again until the form is full.

Example, before and after click:

[image]

Are there any possibilities?

Comment: Are those images or you're drawing it using bezier path!?

Comment: @EugeneGordin Thx for your comment. I'm really new to drawing etc. So I don't know what you are talking about. I'm actually trying a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

This how you draw the second picture:

```
[[NSColor redColor]set];

NSRect rect1 = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 40, 40);
NSBezierPath* rectangle = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect1];
[rectangle setLineWidth:3.0];
[[NSColor redColor] setStroke];
[rectangle stroke];


NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 40, 20);
[[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect] fill];
```

to draw just the first part, use just the top part of the code with no fill.

Edit: this is for OSX app...for iOS you're using CGRect, UIColor etc.